# Is there a semantic version of the deductive theorem for an arbitrary logic system?

Tags: logic

As far as I know, any logic system always defines its own semantics $\models$, but doesn't necessarily have a proof system or $\vdash$ which is complete and sound with respect to $\models$.

In an arbitrary logic system (not necessarily FOL or propositional logic), is there $\models$ version of deductive theorem ($\Phi \vdash \phi$ and $ \vdash (\Phi \to \phi)$ are equivalent in FOL)  ? In other words, are $\Phi \models \phi$ and $ \models (\Phi \to \phi)$ equivalent, or one implies the other?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. In prop logic, if **A ⊨ B**, then **⊨ A → B**.

Comment: The same holds for Fol, with usual "restrictions".

Comment: For an Hilbert-style proof system, like e.g. Enderton's one, the result is straightforward "cooking together" Completeness for FOL (page 135), Deduction Th (page 118) and Soundness Th (page 131).

Comment: There is nothing one can prove for "arbitrary logic system", but if → is interpreted semantically in the usual way, i.e. as the material conditional, then the "semantic deduction theorem" trivially follows.

Comment: @Conifold Does  "deduction theorem"  hold in any proof system/calculus?

Comment: No, but [deduction theorem in a proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) isn't semantic, it is syntactic.

Comment: @Conifold I know it is not semantic. What does your reply mean for answering my question?

Comment: It means that if you want a "semantic" deduction theorem you should be talking not about a proof system but about its interpretations. And then it turns on how → is interpreted in its models. That is if by "semantic deduction theorem" you mean "if A ⊨ B then ⊨ A → B". If you mean instead "if A ⊨ B then ⊢ A → B" then proof system is relevant, but this would be false for any incomplete system.

Comment: "arbitrary logic system" What exactly do you mean by this? There are various notions of "logical system" kicking around, and the answer is going to depend on which you use. (Indeed, for some it won't even make sense: what about a logic which doesn't have implication in the first place?)

Comment: I just wonder if deduction theorem is required or common in semantics or proof system of a logic system @NoahSchweber

Comment: With a liberal enough notion of "logic system", you can easily define  ⊨ and → in a way that they diverge. E.g., take classical logic except that you define →to have the truth table of, say, ∧. In this ad hoc logic system, the semantic version of the deduction theorem obviously no longer holds.

Comment: @lemontree the motivation behind my questions is that deduction theorem clears my confusion between \vdash and \to by relating them together, so I think the theorem is worth for a reasonable logic system. Similarly it would be nice to have a semantic version to clear confusion between \models and \to. The logic system you made up is very useless.

Comment: You never asked for a useful logic system, just for a logic system -- and what exactly makes a system "useless" to you? That's exactly why you need to define more rigorously what you mean by a "logic system".